# How to create card using tremor, and i got this error?

Tags: npm, next.js, package, npm-scripts, card

```
'use client'
import { Card, Divider, Subtitle,Text } from "@tremor/react";

export default function Home(){
    return(
        <main>
            <Card>
                <Text>Climate</Text>
                <Subtitle>Weather App with Charts</Subtitle>
            </Card>
        </main>
    )
}
```

i downloaded the @tremor/react ..but the card does not appear as i expected , i tried things that i know like uninstalling and reinstalling the package etc. Help me fix ..